# Validate if sheet exists before deleting

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code where I want to delete the sheets, I noticed that if they do not exist I get an error, how can I validate and delete only if they exist?

I also noticed I get a deleting warning for every single sheet, any way I can prevent from seeing that warning?

```
Sub delete_hours()

Worksheets("8am").Delete
Worksheets("9am").Delete
Worksheets("10am").Delete
Worksheets("11am").Delete
Worksheets("12pm").Delete
Worksheets("1pm").Delete
Worksheets("2pm").Delete
Worksheets("3pm").Delete
Worksheets("4pm").Delete
Worksheets("5pm").Delete
Worksheets("6pm").Delete

End Sub
```

if you find a better way to do this let me know.

Thanks all,

Comment: To suppress warnings look at the help on Application.DisplayAlerts and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Delete Existing Worksheets

- You need the first three procedures: `TESTdeleteWorksheetsFromList` calls `deleteWorksheetsFromList` which calls `getWorksheetNames`.
- `TESTgetWorksheetNames` just tests `getWorksheetNames`.
- It surely can be done much simpler, but I had this idea...

**The Flow** (`deleteWorksheetsFromList`)

- The values from the `DeleteList` are written to the `delNames` array.
- All worksheet names are written to the `allNames` array.
- `Application.Match` is 'applied' to both arrays resulting in `Matches` array.
- `Matches` array is looped through to write 'matches' to the 'beginning' of `delNames` array.
- `delNames` array is resized to the number of found matches.
- `delNames` array is used to delete the worksheets in one go.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TESTdeleteWorksheetsFromList()
    Const DeleteList As String _
        = "8am,9am,10am,11am,12pm,1pm,2pm,3pm,4pm,5pm,6pm"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    deleteWorksheetsFromList wb, DeleteList
End Sub

Sub deleteWorksheetsFromList( _
        wb As Workbook, _
        ByVal DeleteList As String, _
        Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = ",")
    Dim delNames() As String: delNames = Split(DeleteList, Delimiter)
    Dim allNames() As String: allNames = getWorksheetNames(wb)
    Dim Matches As Variant: Matches = Application.Match(allNames, delNames, 0)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Matches)
        If IsNumeric(Matches(i)) Then
            delNames(k) = delNames(Matches(i) - 1)
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i
    If k > 0 And k < wb.Sheets.Count Then
        ReDim Preserve delNames(0 To k - 1)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.Worksheets(delNames).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End If
End Sub

Function getWorksheetNames(wb As Workbook) As Variant
    Dim wsCount As Long
    wsCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
    If wsCount > 0 Then
        Dim wsNames() As String
        ReDim wsNames(0 To wsCount - 1)
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim n As Long
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            wsNames(n) = ws.Name
            n = n + 1
        Next ws
        getWorksheetNames = wsNames
    End If
End Function

Sub TESTgetWorksheetNames()
    Debug.Print Join(getWorksheetNames(ThisWorkbook), vbLf)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code prior to attempting deletions:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

When you are done:

```
On Error goto 0
```

That's the quick and dirty solution. You should also use a loop instead of repeating the same code:

```
for i=8 to 12
    sheetname = i & "am"
    sheets.delete(sheetname)
next
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I could use your for to shorten my code, however, I could not see how to avoid the annoying warning when deleting one by one, how can I delete all sheets in the for at once? Additionally I would like to know how to validate if those sheets exist before starting deleting otherwise if they do not exist and I start there is an error message.

Comment: The answer says "you should **also** use...". Ie, wrap that loop with the error handler

Comment: @chrisneilsen 2 + 2 = 4

Comment: @Tarik you _could_ have made it clearer to the OP

Comment: @chrisneilsen I do not spoon feed. Think about it: I already explained how to avoid the error. Then proposed replacement code, guess where the replacement code should go? Give me a break.